# Select2 is not working with webpackEncore

Tags: javascript, symfony, jquery-select2, webpack-encore

I try to use select2 (4.1.0-rc.0) with webpackEncore. I did my import but my input in front is a simple html input and I can't click on it. I don't know what I did wrong.

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css';
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full.js';
import 'select2/dist/js/i18n/fr.js';

$('#postal_code_search_zipcode').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    language: 'fr',
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        cache: false,
        url: $('#postal_code_search_zipcode').data('autocomplete-url'),
        delay: 250,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params => ({
            q: params || '',
        }),
        processResults: data => ({
            results: Object.keys(data).map(value => ({
                id: value,
                text: data[value]
            }))
        })
    }
});
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: what error do you get ? sth. in browser console?

Comment: Nope,no error, I can't click on the input and its a basic html input

Comment: are u sure that '#postal_code_search_zipcode' occurs only 1 time and is actually used? What happens when u paste ur code into console?

Comment: Sure at 100%, there is only this one

Comment: What happens when u paste ur code into console?

Comment: My input (the only one) appear